# Stopping default onOK from dialog closing the dialog for CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am developing a plugin and I need that when the user clicks OK on the dialog I have to do some other processing, so I want to stop the dialog from closing and show an error when the information is wrong.

I've tried to cancel, stop the event, but it didn't work.

```
onOk: function (event) {
            event.cancel();
            event.stop();
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting this property on false will stop the dialog closing:

```
  onOk: function (event, a, b) {
            event.data.hide = false;
  }
```